# Flutter DataTable onTap selects last value

Tags: flutter, datatable, ontap

I am relatively new tro flutter. I am trying to create a DataTable that the user could Tap on and take some action based on which row was clicked. However, when the user taps on any cell, it picks up the last value (bottom left of the table) irrespective of which cell or row is Tap'ed. Also tried `onSelectChanged`

```
List<DataRow> dataRows = [];
    String cellValue = '';
    final formatter = NumberFormat('#,##0;(#,##0)');
    for (int z = 0; z < widget.data.length; z++) {
      dataRows.add(DataRow(
          cells: [],
          onSelectChanged: (selected) {
            if (selected!) {
              debugPrint('row-selected: $cellValue');
            }
          }));
      int ii = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++) {
        ii = i + 1;
        if (columnTypes[i] == 'N') {
          cellValue = formatter.format(double.parse(widget.data[z]['col$ii']));
        } else {
          cellValue = widget.data[z]['col$ii'].toString();
        }
        dataRows[z].cells.add(
              DataCell(
                Text('--$cellValue'),
                onTap: () => {
                  debugPrint(
                      "onTap Pressed ====>$cellValue-------${TimeOfDay.now()}")
                },
              ),
            );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you coded it makes it take the `cellValue` that it was last because it was declared in the outer scope. Try introducing a local variable in the local scope instead by replacing

```
    dataRows[z].cells.add(
          DataCell(
            Text('--$cellValue'),
            onTap: () => {
              debugPrint(
                  "onTap Pressed ====>$cellValue-------${TimeOfDay.now()}")
            },
          ),
        );
```

with

```
    String someString = cellValue;
    dataRows[z].cells.add(
          DataCell(
            Text('--$cellValue'),
            onTap: () => {
              debugPrint(
                  "onTap Pressed ====>$someString -------${TimeOfDay.now()}")
            },
          ),
        );
```

Comment: This is good. Can you please modify your suggested code so that onTap actually removes the row that has been clicked?